# Devise confirmation email is being sent when I don't want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

So here's the tricky thing.

I do want an email to be sent when the user tries to change or update his email address on the site. However, I do not want an email to be send when the user first registers. This is really tough to pull off though because with the confirmable module, I can't seem to have one without the other.

Any ideas on best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the registrationscontroller.

In the create action call resource.skip_confirmation! before resource.save is called.